# Linkedin API : No refresh token with accessToken

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, access-token, refresh-token, oauth-refresh-token

When i use the Linkedin API to get access token, it only works halfway. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&tabs=HTTPS1#step-3-exchange-authorization-code-for-an-access-token), I'm supposed to receive :

- `access_token`
- `expires_in`
- `refresh_token`
- `refresh_token_expires_in`
- `scope`.

But i only receive `access_token`, `expires_in` and `scope`?

Does anyone know why ?

Thanks

```
const data = {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code,
    redirect_uri,
    client_id,
    client_secret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
  }

const authorization = await axios.post(
    `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?${querystring.stringify(data)}`);

console.log("authorization.data", authorization.data);
```

Logs :

```
authorization.data {
  access_token: 'AQX09XfxIcceXWHz9Mutkbjfsj3iqJptsAxrpGxW3anWD-rIh...,
  expires_in: 5183999,
  scope: 'r_liteprofile,w_member_social'
}
```

Comment: Your response as look like the documentation response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application, you need to enable programmatic refresh tokens for partners. if that is not available you will need to go through the authorization flow again to generate a refresh token. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/linkedin/shared/authentication/programmatic-refresh-tokens?context=linkedin%2Fcontext